# How to get Count of value of nested object by linq

Tags: c#, linq

Can anyone please suggest how to get the sum of points from all the `Event` objects by using linq.

```
new Category
{
     CategoryId = "NUTR",
     CategoryName = "NUTR",
     CategoryDescription = "NUTR Desc",
     TotalPoints = "100",
     Events = new List<Event>
           {
             new Event{Firstname = "HELEN",Surname = "BECKETT", 
                 Points = "10", Description = "NUTR Desc",Eventdate = "2013/04/19",EntityNumber = "1203206956"},
             new Event{Firstname = "PAUL",Surname = "BECKETT", 
                 Points = "90", Description = "NUTR Desc",Eventdate = "2013/06/19",EntityNumber = "1203206957"}
           }
}
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to flatten the list of `events`, then do the sum:

```
var totalPoints = categories
    .SelectMany(c => c.Events)
    .Sum(e => Convert.ToInt32(e.Points));
```

Answer (score -1):

If I correclty understand the question this can be achieved by `Linq`
I suggest you to change the type of Points from string to int if possible

```
Category cat = ....

var countEvents = cat.Sum(i=>i.Events.Sum(ii=>ii.Points));
```

Comment: You return a number of events, not sum of points from all events. Furthermore, why call `Count()` on a list when it implements `ICollection<T>` and therefore has `Count` property.

Comment: Correct, I have changed the query to `Sum()`

Comment: Still not correct. `Points` is `string`, not `int`.

Comment: Read my complete answer, there I have written that I suggest to change the type for Points

Comment: How nice of you. But if he doesn't want to change it, than your solution won't help him. Suggesting should be the second part of the answer, the first one should provide a working solution.